# Quickest way to serialize a DataSet in a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, serialization, odbc

I have a dataset fetched from a ODBC data source (MySQL), I need to temporarily put it into a SQL Server DB to be fetched by another process (and then transformed further).

Instead of creating a nicely formatted database table I'd rather have one field of type text and whack the stuff there.

This is only a data migration exercise, a one-off, so I don't care about elegance, performance, or any other aspects of it.

All I want is to be able to de-serialize the "text-blob" (or binary) back into anything resembling a dataset. A Dictionary object would do the trick too.

Any quick fixes for me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataSet.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) to write out your "text-blob" then use [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx) later when you want to translate the "text-blob" back into a DataSet to perform whatever subsequent manipulations you want to do.

Comment: I'll use that with a StringWriter then :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do everything on a SSIS package, extract from MySQL, transform as you wish  and load wherever you need it?

Comment: I suggest you try, things like this are exactly the goal. If you would like to learn, I can recommend this tutorial: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/stratesql/2011/1/1/31-days-of-ssis-_1320_-the-introduction/